# Is it possible to open a word document from a particular location in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open a word document from a particular location in C# using:

```
 string str2 = "Docname.doc"
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + str2);
```

My problem is that above code create and open a word doc but i want to open any existing doc file at any particular location.

Comment: So are you looking for a search feature?

Comment: The question is very misleading in it's wording.

Comment: Actually i want to open an existing doc file which is placed in App_Data folder

Comment: You people are killing this guy with downvotes, he's a new user, and this misunderstanding of HTTP oriented applications is something everyone struggles with at some point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the document and write it to response as a `MemoryStream`. I think this should work:

```cs
var fileStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"path/to/document.doc");
var stream = new MemoryStream(fileStream);
stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","Attachment;filename=documentName.doc");
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
```

Comment: Thanks , it works but i want insert string into this document.can u please help me on that

Comment: If I understand you right you want to write in the .doc file?

Comment: yes i want to insert text in this file which is dynamic ,for that i have use a string variable.

Comment: I don't really know what you want to achieve... In your question you put code using response, which is used to modify http response and you're now asking to modify .doc file which is a completely different matter. Take a look at [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx) for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks maremp for all your help.Actually i want to open a word document from existing folder using C# and add html values in that which shows dynamic data in the word document with proper html format(like tables,font-size,font-color,etc)

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP response can't contain a reference to a file path on the client computer, if that's what you're after then the answer is no.

If the file is on the server and you want it to open on the client, then you need to read the entire contents of the file and write those contents to the response.